# Motionlayout and visibility make layout different to the Constraintlayout

Tags: android, visibility, android-constraintlayout, android-motionlayout

I am converting the current constraintlayout to MotionLayout for the animation. What I do is quite simple, when the user scroll the second recycler view , the first recycler view should be hide. And the header should be visibile once I got the data from the API. So my layout is something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background_gradient"
        app:layoutDescription="@xml/fragment_scene">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvList"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_24dp"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
            tools:itemCount="3"
            tools:listitem="@layout/view_items" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tlContainer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rvList"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimaryBlue"
            app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"
            app:tabInlineLabel="false"
            app:tabMode="auto"
            app:tabPaddingEnd="@dimen/spacing_8dp"
            app:tabPaddingStart="@dimen/spacing_8dp"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Roboto.Bold"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/white50">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Favorites" />

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    <include
            android:id="@+id/containerHeader"
            layout="@layout/view_header"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tlContainer"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvList2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/containerHeader"
            tools:listitem="@layout/view_list_item" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/colorAccent">

        <TextView
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Home"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Roboto.Bold"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_16"
                tools:text="Home" />

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivSearch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/spacing_8dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp" />

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivOpenDetail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/spacing_8dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_settings_white_24dp" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

And the scene xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/expand">
        <Constraint android:id="@id/containerHeader">
            <PropertySet
                    app:applyMotionScene="false"
                    app:visibilityMode="ignore" />
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/collapse">
        <Constraint
                android:id="@id/rvList"
                android:alpha="0"
                motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
        <Constraint
                android:id="@id/containerHeader">
            <PropertySet
                    app:applyMotionScene="false"
                    app:visibilityMode="ignore" />
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>

    <Transition
            app:constraintSetEnd="@id/collapse"
            app:constraintSetStart="@id/expand">

        <OnSwipe
                app:dragDirection="dragUp"
                app:touchAnchorId="@id/rvList2" />
    </Transition>
</MotionScene>
```

The strange thing is , I set `containerHeader` as `View.Gone` on the first time and the view visibility should be depended on the api response. However, when I run the app the containerHeader occupy the space after I set `View.Visbile` for the container header but cannot show any content. I cannot find any clue about it.

Am I doing wrong with MotionLayout? Appreciate any help or advice.